# \newcommand argument confusion

Tags: macros

I'm trying to work through *LaTeX Beginner's Guide* by Stefan Kottwitz. Here's where I got stumped:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\keyword}[2][\bfseries]{{#1#2}}
\begin{document}
\keyword{Grouping} by curly braces limits the
\keyword{scope} of \keyword[\itshape]{declarations}.
\end{document}
```

The output adds boldface to "Groupings" and "scope," while "declarations" is italicized. I do not understand this syntax. I vaguely get that `\bfseries` is the "default" and `\itshape` got specifically subbed in for "declarations" but I cannot follow Kottwitz's explanation:

> Let's look again at the bold marked line in the code. By using `[\bfseries]`, we introduced an optional parameter. We refer to it with `#1`. Its default value is `\bfseries`. Since we used a declaration this time, we added a pair of braces to ensure that only the keyword is
>   affected by the declaration. Later in the document, we gave `[\itshape]`
>   to `\keyword`, changing the default formatting to italics.

Can I get a second opinion/explanation of what is going on here?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436).  The additional pair of braces was need to introduce a group so that any switch type macro passed in as the optional `#1` had it's effect limited to be within the text (`#2`) of this macro.

Comment: I'm reading the same book at this very moment. One thing Stefan did not include was how to specify multiple _mandatory_ arguments when calling the command (`\mycommand{mandatory_arg1}{mandatory_arg2}`).

Answer (score 166):

The syntax of `\newcommand` *without* an optional argument is the following:

```
\newcommand{<name>}[<args>]{ <code> }
```

Where `<args>` is the number of arguments (ranges from 1-9).  Within the `<code>` part of the definition, each of the arguments is marked with a `#` sign: so the first argument is `#1` the second is `#2` etc. So if we create a macro `\reverseconcat` which has three obligatory arguments and concatenates them in reverse order, we would define it as follows:

```
\newcommand{\reverseconcat}[3]{#3#2#1} % version 1
```

And we would use it as follows:

```
\reverseconcat{A}{B}{C}
```

which would output "CBA"

Now suppose we wanted our command to make the output bold.  To do this we want to add `\bfseries` in our code.  Suppose we did this:

```
\newcommand{\reverseconcat}[3]{\bfseries#3#2#1} % version 2
```

If we pass the same arguments to this command however, we run into a problem: the code part acts as if we just typed `\bfseries CBA` in our document, and since `\bfseries` is a switch, it will make all following text bold, which is not what we want.  So in this case, we need to limit the scope of the `\bfseries` by adding braces around the code part.

```
\newcommand{\reverseconcat}[3]{{\bfseries#3#2#1}} % version 3
```

Now when we pass the same arguments to this command it's as if we typed `{\bfseries CBA}` in our document, which is what we want.

Now suppose we want our command to have an optional argument. By definition, the optional argument is *always* the argument designated `#1` (i.e. the first argument). However, since the command still has a first argument even if it's left out by the user, we still need to provide a value for it. So the syntax of the command changes:

```
\newcommand{<name>}[<args>][<first argument value>]{<code>}
```

Now let's make our reverse concatenation macro take an optional argument that specifies how to format the reversed text.  In this case, our new macro will then take *four* arguments (assuming we still want the 3 arguments we originally had.)

So our new command looks like this:

```
\newcommand{\reverseconcat}[4][\bfseries]{{#1#4#3#2}}
```

This macro will behave exactly like version 3 above, so `\reverseconcat{A}{B}{C}` will output "**CBA**". Notice, however, that because we've added the optional argument, the numbers used for the reversing part are different: they start at `#2` because `#1` is the optional argument.

Our new command, however, allows us to specify a different value for the first argument, however, so if we don't want the text to be bold, we can pass `\itshape` to make it italic:

```
\reverseconcat[\itshape]{A}{B}{C}
```

and this will produce "*CBA*"

As Przemysław Scherwentke says in his answer, you could actually pass anything to this command, not just a formatting command, so if, for example, you forgot the `\` on `\itshape`:

```
\reverseconcat[itshape]{A}{B}{C}
```

The output would be "itshapeCBA"

This last example shows that expecting the user to pass a command to another command probably isn't the best idea, since you'd like the example above to produce an error rather than produce incorrect output. But solving that problem here would take us too far afield.

Comment: Off topic. In Poland it is 6 o'clock now. CBA (Centralne Biuro Antykorupcyjne) is an organization like FBI. Typical time of their action is 6 o'clock. :-) Alas, I cannot additionaly upvote conotations.

Comment: what about multiple optional arguments ?

Comment: @Welgriv Multiple optional arguments are not possible using `\newcommand` syntax. You can use the `xparse` syntax `\NewDocumentCommand` to achieve this however. See e.g. [xparse: Define new command with multiple optional parameters](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/33749/2693). But depending on the use case it might be better to use a key-value syntax instead.

Comment: @AlanMunn Could you add an example of the key-value syntax?

Comment: @Andyc I don't think adding a key-value example would be helpful to this particular question, which answers a relatively elementary question that can be helpful to many new LaTeX users. There are plenty of key-value examples on the site. See e.g. [Simple key-value example](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/543755), [newcommand key value](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/58069), and [How to create a command with key values?](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/34312) and for package options [key-value syntax in package options](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/417704).

Answer (score 57):

There are two separate things happening here, and I think perhaps tackling them simultaneously is creating confusion. The first thing is *optional arguments* and the second thing is *braces for scoping*.

### Optional arguments

When you define a command

```
\newcommand\isgreat[2]{#1 thinks #2 is great.}
```

you put `{` and `}` around the definition. Then occurrences of `\isgreat` are replaced as you'd expect:

```
\isgreat{John}{Stack Exchange} He uses it every day.
```

> John thinks Stack Exchange is great. He uses it every day.

If you had written this instead:

```
\newcommand\isgreat[2][John]{#1 thinks #2 is great.}
```

then the first argument is optional. If you *don't* give it, it defaults to `John`

```
\isgreat{LaTeX}
```

> John thinks LaTeX is great.

and if you *do* give it, you have to put it in square brackets.

```
\isgreat[Gary]{LaTeX}
```

> Gary thinks LaTeX is great.

### Braces for scoping

When you write `\bfseries`, that's like clicking the "Bold" toolbar button in Microsoft Word -- everything you type from then on will be bold.

```
John thinks LaTeX is \bfseries great. He uses it every day.
```

> John thinks LaTeX is **great. He uses it every day.**

In order to restrict the boldness to a specific part of the text, you can enclose it in braces.

```
John thinks LaTeX is {\bfseries great}. He uses it every day.
```

> John thinks LaTeX is **great**. He uses it every day.

### Finally

In Stefan's example, LaTeX replaces

```
\keyword{Grouping} by curly braces
```

with

```
{\bfseries Grouping} by curly braces
```

Do you see why the extra curly braces in the `\newcommand` are needed? One pair is needed to provide the definition, and one pair to restrict the scope of the `\bfseries` command.

Answer (score 13):

`\newcommand{\keyword}[2][\bfseries]{{#1#2}}` is a macro with 2 parameters and an optional argument. If it is not specified, `\bfseries` is taken as the first argument. If you write, e.g., `\keyword[AAA]{declarations}`, you will obtain `AAAdeclarations` in the roman font.

Comment: So the first parameter is either the default `[\bfseries]` or whatever you may add to override the default, the second parameter is the word or phrase you want to apply this all to. The book's previous example, `\newcommand{\keyword}[1]{\textbf{#1}}`, can only make the word or phrase boldface.

Comment: @user78162 Yes, exactly!

Answer (score 2):

I think the puzzling part, as pointed out profusely in [John's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/117391/23166), is that the sentence

> Since we used a declaration this time, we added a pair of braces to ensure that only the keyword is affected by the declaration.

refers declaration which may be confused with something related to the *declaration* of a new command.

Instead, it refers to the fact that the expansion of `\newcommand` contents will not be automatically scoped, and in the specific case of using `\bfseries` and other declarations, you will have to take car of the scoping youself, by letting the last argument of `newcommand` be scoped: `{#1#2}` rather than #1#2

maybe starting with a different example helps:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\dummy}[2][0]{#2^#1}
\begin{document}

the default is $\dummy{A}$ but you can switch to $\dummy[2]{A}$

\end{document}
```