# How to define newcommand to rotate text in table with origin parameter option?

Tags: macros, rotating

I'm rotating my text in a table cell with a `\newcommand{\up}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}}` definition. Sometimes it's good to rotate and align text left/right not centered.

So I would like to change that definition to take a second value that can be `origin=l`.

I found [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/117358/newcommand-argument-confusion#117365) but I'm not able to get a functional `newcommand` with second parameter something like `\newcommand{\up{#2}}{\rotatebox[origin=#2]{90}}`.

I wold like to use it like this: `\up{l}{text}`

Can somebody help me with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want something like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand{\up}[2]{\rotatebox[origin=#1]{90}{#2}}

\begin{document}

        \begin{tabular}{ll}
            \up{c}{First First} & \up{l}{First Second}\\
            Second First & Second Second
        \end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Exactly works perfect. Can you explane why the number [2] is in brackets at the start and the alignment parameter is #1 followed by a #2 at the end? i don't understand the syntaxt here...

Comment: The syntax of `\newcommand` is: `\newcommand{\mycommand}[number of arguments]{definition of the command}`. You can refer to the arguments as #1, #2, #3 etc.