# \newcommand with arguments that itself are \newcommands

Tags: math-mode, macros, amsmath

I currently fail at creating macros that are capable of simplifying some math notation. I'm using two separate macros. One

```
\usepackage{xargs}
\usepackage{xifthen}

\newcommandx\vecidx[3][2= , 3= ]{  
    \mathbf{#1}^{
        \ifthenelse{\isempty{#2}}{}{\scriptscriptstyle (#2)}
    }_{
        \ifthenelse{\isempty{#3}}{}{\scriptscriptstyle #3}
    }
}
```

helps me in writing vector notation.`\vecidx{z}[1]` gives
`$\mathbf_{z}^{\scriptscriptstyle (1)}$`, `\vecidx{z}[1][ij]` gives `$\mathbf_{z}^{\scriptscriptstyle (1)}_{ij}$`. The other macro is used in partial derivatives

```
\newcommandx\pd[2][1= ]{  
    \frac{\partial #1}{\partial #2}
}
```

Things work as expected as long as I don't pass `\vecidx{z}[1]` as an argument to `\pd`, like `\pd[\vecidx{x}[1]]{\vecidx{z}[1]}` which gives rise to an error `Missing } inserted ...`.

I found that escaping `\pd[{\vecidx{x}[1]}]{\vecidx{z}[1]}` helps, but all those brackets make it hard to read. Is there anything I can do to simplify the syntax?

Comment: Off-topic: You know packages like skmath and physics?

Comment: @Johannes_B no, these packages are new to me. skmath seems to have a bit of what I need. Thanks for the link!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like a job for `xparse`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\NewDocumentCommand{\vecidx}{moo} %
  {%
    \mathbf{#1}%
      \IfNoValueF{#2}{^{\scriptscriptstyle (#2)}}%
      \IfNoValueF{#3}{_{\scriptscriptstyle (#3)}}%
  }
\NewDocumentCommand{\pd}{O{}m}
  {\frac{\partial #1}{\partial #2}}
\begin{document}
$\pd[\vecidx{x}[1]]{\vecidx{z}[1]}$
\end{document}
```

(I'm not sure I'd be keen on using this syntax myself: tends to hide what is going on.)

This works as the `xparse` implementation of optional arguments using bracket-matching: it doesn't get 'confused' by the nested square brackets.

Note the syntax for specifying arguments:

- `m`: mandatory argument in braces
- `o`: optional argument in square brackets, which returns the special `-NoValue-` marker if the argument is not given
- `O{<default>}`: optional argument in square brackets with `<default>` returned
  if the argument is not given

Comment: works like a charm, thanks! no sure what does `moo`and `O{}m` elements are doing though. Guess that's best understood from the package description.

Comment: thanks! One more minor thing, when trying todo `\vecidx{y}[][i]` I do see empty superscript brackets. Do you know how to fix this? I guess that's because [] is an empty value and not a no-value.

Comment: Was able to fix the above myself using `\IfNoValueF{#2}{\@ifmtarg{#2}{}{^{\scriptscriptstyle (#2)}}}%`. Taken from https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33749/xparse-define-new-command-with-multiple-optional-parameters?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa